# Call a function when it is stored as dictionary value

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def test():
     print "printing from test func"

dic = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':test}
if len(dic) == 3:
     print (dic['c'])

output:
<function test at 0x106887578>
```

This code prints the function object as output, how to get the print statement from test function as output.

Comment: Have you tried calling the function? And you probably want to return in the function instead of printing.

Comment: You need to using the [calling syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls). I.e. `f()`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simply call `dic['c']()` to run your function. Hope I helped!